# How to avoid implementing component over and over

Tags: java, swing

For example, I have 20 different `JTextField` and lets say I need to set text to all "random", so I don't want to do like:

```
field1.setText("Random");
field2.setText("Random");
field3.setText("Random");
.
.
.
field20.setText("Random");
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Put them in a list and iterate over them? `for(Textfield f : fields) f.setText("Random");`

Comment: Use of arrays, collections and for loops are all part of basic introductory Java. I have to wonder if you may be putting the cart before the horse -- learning Swing or any other complex GUI before learning the basic rudiments of Java. Do yourself a favor, get a decent intro to Java book, the Head First book is a good one, and go through it first before trying the more complex Java stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is quite a basic question. You can do this :

```
Stream.of(field1,field2,...,field3).forEach(f -> f.setText("Random"));
```

or without Java 8 :

```
JTextField fields = Arrays.asList(field1,field2,...,field3);
for (JTextField field : fields)
    field.setText("Random");
```

Or, if you don't need to keep a reference to your fields :

```
for (int i=0 ; i<20 ; i++) {
    JTextField field = new JTextField("Random");
    // place your field in the UI
}
```

Comment: I guess the code of @vivan-maya is generated code with a GUI builder that stores the fields as properties, so your approach with the references would probably be the best shot.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
JTextField[] textFields = new JTextField[20];
for (int i =0; i< fields.length; i++) {
    //init here text fields
    textFields[i].setText("Random");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create the `JTextField`s in an array or a `Collection` and then iterate over the contents of the array.

For instance:

```
List<JTextField> myTextFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  myTextFields.add(new JTextField()); //Instantiate the textfields
  //Do whatever other initialization, if you can do it in a loop (like position, etc.)

  myTextFields.get(i).setText("Random"); //Set text on all of them.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to also cover the possibility which was not mentioned so far:

You could (although you really should not *in most cases*) inherit from `JTextField` and do your business e.g. in the constructor. Or you can use a factory-method.

(sample below is untested code written with one hand)

```
class MyTextField extends JTextField {
  public MyTextField() {
     setText("Random");
  }
}

/* in other file */
class MyTextFildFactory {
  public static JTextField createTextField() {
     JTextField field = new JTextField();
     field.setText("Random");
     return field;
  }
}
```